# c++ namespace with class

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

`ns.cpp`:

```
    #include <iostream>

    namespace ns {        // want to access this globally
      class A ;
    }

    class ns::A {
    public:
     int x1;
     char s1[128];
    };

    int main()
    {
    int doit();
    //using namespace ns;

      ns::A a;

      a.x1= 2;

      std::cout << "pre " << a.x1 << "\n" ;
      doit();
      std::cout << "post " << a.x1 << "\n" ;
    }
```

`ns_call.cpp`:

```
    namespace ns {
     class A;
    }

    class ns::A {
    public:
     int x1;
     char s1[];
    };

    using namespace ns;

    int
    doit()
    {
       extern ns::A a;

       a.x1= 100;
    }
```

in ns.cpp, a class is declard within a namespace.
the class is defined followed.

Variables in the class are to be accessed globally. This
is the goal of the namespace.

ns_call.cpp  then access 1 of the class' member, x1.

The 2 files were compiled OK with gcc 5.4.1  in Fedora 14.
run output is:

```
pre 2
post 2
```

I expected 'post 100' because i wanted to access int x1 in class A
globally.

Comment: This doesn't link: `undefined reference to 'a'` (it's declared inside `main`, not globally).

Comment: This is a violation of the ODR -- the definition of `ns::A` in ns_capp.cpp differs from the one in ns.cpp.

Comment: Move the "ns::A a;" up 6 lines.  It works then.

Answer (score 3):

None of `extern`, `namespace`s or forward declarations seem to mean what you think they mean.

If you want to introduce a name that can be accessed my multiple translation units (what you seem to mean when you say "globally"), you put those definitions in a header file, and `#include` that header from wherever you want to use it.

What you're actually doing is introducing `class A` over and over again in every translation unit (eg, in each CPP file).  This is a violation of the ODR at best.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just gonna help you fix your problem, while you absolutely have to heed the other answers about ODR (One Definition Rule) and fix your design.

in the `ns.cpp` file, you have to move the line `ns::A a;` out of the `main()` function. Put it at the file scope (e.g. right before `main`.) Also, in the `ns_call.cpp` file, move the line `extern ns::A a;` out of the function too.

Note: you may or may not have to do the second part, and this whole method might or might not work. I don't have access to a compiler right now.

Again I have to agree with other comments that this design is flawed and it *will* cause you headaches.